# Flutter breaks on execution when using speech_recognition and workmanager

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to use speech_recognition  and workmanager together in my flutter application, but for some reason im not able to make it work.

- If i use speech_recognition without workmanager, everything works fine just adding it in the pubspec.yaml
- When i try to use workmanager its also working. For that, in addition to the pubspec.yaml dependecy, it requires some more changes

In AndroidManifest.xml, i changed:

```
<application android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"  ... />
```

for:

```
<application android:name=".Application" ... />
```

and created Application.kt:

```
package com.company.app

import be.tramckrijte.workmanager.WorkmanagerPlugin
import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class Application : FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        WorkmanagerPlugin.setPluginRegistrantCallback(this)
    }

    override fun registerWith(reg: PluginRegistry?) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(reg)
    }
}
```

- The problems appear when i try to use them together.

Flutter doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.6, on Linux, locale es_ES.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 1.9.1+hotfix.6 at /home/fsalguero/software/flutter
    • Framework revision 68587a0916 (hace 3 meses), 2019-09-13 19:46:58 -0700
    • Engine revision b863200c37
    • Dart version 2.5.0


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /home/fsalguero/Android/Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /home/fsalguero/software/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /home/fsalguero/software/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 41.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.40.2)
    • VS Code at /usr/share/code
    • Flutter extension version 3.7.1

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • SM A505FN • R58M76BADQK • android-arm64 • Android 9 (API 28)

• No issues found!
```

Versions from pubspec.yaml:

```
speech_recognition: ^0.3.0+1
workmanager: ^0.1.5
```

I get this error on execution:

```
D/AndroidRuntime( 3241): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime( 3241): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 3241): Process: com.zink.trackely, PID: 3241
E/AndroidRuntime( 3241): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.app.Activity.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
E/AndroidRuntime( 3241):    at bz.rxla.flutter.speechrecognition.SpeechRecognitionPlugin.<init>(SpeechRecognitionPlugin.java:46)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3241):    at bz.rxla.flutter.speechrecognition.SpeechRecognitionPlugin.registerWith(SpeechRecognitionPlugin.java:38)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3241):    at io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:40)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3241):    at com.zink.trackely.Application.registerWith(Application.kt:15)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3241):    at be.tramckrijte.workmanager.BackgroundWorker$doWork$1.run(BackgroundWorker.kt:75)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3241):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3241):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3241):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3241):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7076)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3241):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3241):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3241):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
I/Process ( 3241): Sending signal. PID: 3241 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
```